# Get value from collection field in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have collection form and need to access the value to show in my view. The problem is seems the key variable declared as Integer and I got error like this :

> Impossible to access an attribute ("nama") on a integer variable ("0")
>   in SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi:manage.html.twig at line 65

Here my Twig :

```
{% for key, absensi in form_edit %}
    <li>{{ form_edit.vars.value.statusS.key.nama }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

If I change `{{ form_edit.vars.value.statusS.key.nama }}` into `{{ form_edit.vars.value.statusS.1.nama }}` its works fine.

Here my controller :

```
/* Show data */
        $emShow = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $collectionAbsensi = new CollectionAbsensi();
        foreach ($entityGrupPelajar as $temp) {
            $entity = new DftAbsensi();
            $entity = $emShow->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi')->findOneBy(array('idGrupPelajar' => $temp, 'tanggal' => $tanggal));
            if ($entity)
            {
                $entityPelajar = $emShow->getRepository('SifoAdminBundle:MstPelajar')->find($temp->getIdPelajar());
                $dftAbsensi = new DftAbsensi();
                $dftAbsensi->setId($entity->getId())
                    ->setIdGrupPelajar($entity->getIdGrupPelajar())
                    ->setTanggal($entity->getTanggal())
                    ->setStatus($entity->getStatus())
                    ->setNis($entityPelajar->getNis())
                    ->setNama($entityPelajar->getNama())
                ;
                $collectionAbsensi->getStatusS()->add($dftAbsensi);
            }
        }
        $emShow->flush();

        $formEdit = $this->createForm(new CollectionAbsensiType(), $collectionAbsensi);
        $formEdit->add('save', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-info')));

        return $this->render('SifoAdminBundle:DftAbsensi:manage.html.twig', array(
            'form_edit'      => $formEdit->createView(),
        ));
```

I have searched for this problem also read the issue [#902](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/902) but still this problems occurs in my Symfony 2.4 on PHP 5.4

Is there any ways to get that value in iteration without key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

`form_edit.vars.value.statusS.key.nama`

To

`form_edit.vars.value.statusS[key].nama`

The former is equivalent to `$form_edit['vars']['value']['statusS']['key']['nama']` (which does not exist) while the latter is equivalent to `$form_edit['vars']['value']['statusS'][$key]['nama']`

Comment: Works great, Thank you. and this is how I call the form `form_edit.statusS[key].status` ^^~